# xamarin android button event

Tags: android, events, button, xamarin

I've tried to test **Button** event but I'm getting  NULL referenge error.
There are three layouts :Main, simple_fragments and Stock

There are one button (btSearch) and on edittext in the Stock -layout.
Now when I try to create click-event:

> Button bt= FindViewById(Resources.Id.btSearch)
>
> bt.Click+=Bt_Click; <-- this cause error.

If I put button to main layout and create button event everything works fine.

How create button events to each layout ?

Here is picture from MainActivity

Lets hope that you can see read it.

Comment: are you using `SetContentView(...)` and using correct layout with it?

Comment: post your function and logcat

Comment: Here are code from MainActivity

Comment: The code is too long to put it here but  MainActivity --> onCreate void, have I the :
base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
...
Button bt = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btSearch); //this button is located in Stock layout
            bt.Click += Bt_Click;

Comment: edit your question

Comment: I tried to put hole code there but there comes error messges part of code (press ctrl K but it does not helped).
Now I added a picture which contains code but I am not sure is it visible .

Comment: My code is from example https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/tab_layout/actionbar/
I just added one layout (with button end edittext) and there in the WhatsOnFragment  I create Stock -layout instead of simple_fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the comments, you are setting the content view to the wrong layout.

From your comment:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
```

Yet, going from your post, the `btSearch` button is on the `Stock` layout. So you need to change that line to...

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Stock);
```

`FindViewById` will return null if the view isn't found in the layout set in `SetContentView`.

Comment: But if situation is it that there are buttons in layout (--> that shoud open Stock -layout) and  in the Stock has button which shoud do something.

Comment: Sure, that code will work if the Stock layout also has a button that has the `id` of `btSearch`. If it's named something else, then it's not going to work.